# Simplify series of string manipulations in Ruby

Tags: ruby, strings

I have a series of string manipulation, I realize this with the following code. I want it to be more elegant and readable such as `str.sub_heading().sub_codeblock()...`, how could I rewrite my code?

````
def sub_heading(str)
  str.gsub!(/^(#+)\w+/) {|m|  m.gsub("#", "=")}
  str.gsub!(/^(=+)(.+)/, '\1 \2 \1')
end

def sub_codeblock(str)
  str.gsub!(/```(.+\n)((.|\n)+)```/,  '{{{#!text_pygments \1\2}}}')
end

def sub_inlinecode(str)
  str.gsub!(/`(.+)`/, '{{{\1}}}')
end

def sub_bold(str)
  str.gsub!(/([^\w]|^)\*\*\w[\w\s\d\-_'"]*\*\*([^\w]|$)/) {|m|  m.gsub("**", "'''")}
end

def sub_italic(str)
  str.gsub!(/([^*]|^)\*\w[\w\s\d\-_'"]*\*([^*]|$)/) {|m|  m.gsub("*", "''")}
end

def sub_link(str)
  str.gsub!(/\[\[(.+)\|(.+)\]\]/, '[[\2|\1]]')
end

sub_heading(inputdata)
sub_codeblock(inputdata)
sub_inlinecode(inputdata)
sub_bold(inputdata)
sub_italic(inputdata)
sub_link(inputdata)
````

Answer (score 1):

You may collect the replacements in a Hash and call them on after the other.

```
replacements = { 
  /1/ => ' one ',
  /2/ => ' two ',
  /([34])/ => ' (\1 is three or four) ',
}

test = '123'
replacements.each{|regex, repl|
  test.gsub!(regex, repl)
}
p test
```

The `gsub`-version with blocks need a little trick:

```
replacements = { 
  /1/ => ' one ',
  /2/ => ' two ',
  /3/ => Proc.new{|m| m*2},
}

test = '123'
replacements.each{|regex, repl|
  if repl.is_a?(Proc)
    test.gsub!(regex){|m| repl.call(m)}
  else
  test.gsub!(regex, repl)
  end
}
p test
```

In your case you may define your replacements with:

````
Replacements = {
  # sub_heading 
  /^(#+)\w+/                                    => Proc.new{|m|  m.gsub("#", "=")},
  /^(=+)(.+)/                                   => '\1 \2 \1',
  # sub_codeblock
  /```(.+\n)((.|\n)+)```/                       => '{{{#!text_pygments \1\2}}}',
  # sub_inlinecode 
   /`(.+)`/                                     => '{{{\1}}}',
  # sub_bold
  /([^\w]|^)\*\*\w[\w\s\d\-_'"]*\*\*([^\w]|$)/  => Proc.new{|m|  m.gsub("**", "'''")},
  # sub_italic
  /([^*]|^)\*\w[\w\s\d\-_'"]*\*([^*]|$)/        => Proc.new{|m|  m.gsub("*", "''")},
  # sub_link
  /\[\[(.+)\|(.+)\]\]/                          => '[[\2|\1]]',
}

def my_replace(inputstring)
  Replacements.each{|regex, repl|
    if repl.is_a?(Proc)
      inputstring.gsub!(regex){|m| repl.call(m)}
    else
    inputstring.gsub!(regex, repl)
    end
  }
end

my_replace(inputdata)
````

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to be more elegant and readable such as
>   str.sub_heading().sub_codeblock()

1. If you want to call directly on String object you must open the class and add the methods.
2. If you want "str.method1.method2...." (which is the correct approach) you *must not* use in-place methods like sub!. So:

   ```
   class String
    def sub_heading(str)
      gsub(/^(#+)\w+/) { |m| m.gsub("#", "=") }.
       gsub(/^(=+)(.+)/, '\1 \2 \1')
    end

    ....
   end
   ```

You get the idea for the others.

However, I woulnd't open a standard class to add such specific functions, write a class-method with this always (remember: create new strings, don't update).